# Como llamar método de un JPanel a un JFrame en Java

Tags: java, netbeans, java-swing, javafx

Espero puedan ayudarme, quiero llamar un método que tengo realizado en mi JPanel.

Es decir si yo coloco la variable `tab = 1` y el método `cargar Datos();` dentro de algún botón del mismo Panel, me muestra los datos registrados en mi Table, pero lo que quiero, es que al presionar un Button de otro formulario me cague los datos de mi table.

Ya hace la carga de datos, en mi table, pero tengo que tener un botón adicional que al presionarlo me muestra los datos, y lo que quiero es que al momento de presionar el botón desde otro Frame me muestre los datos de mi tabla.

Método de mi JPanel

```
public void cargarDatos() {

    switch (tab) {
        case 1:
            numAlumno = alumno.getAlumnos();
            alumno.searchAlumno(Table_AlumnosRegistrados, "", num_registro, pageSize);
            maxReg = numAlumno.size();
            break;
    }
    pageCount = (maxReg / pageSize);
    //Ajuste el numero de la pagina si la ultima pagina contiene una parte de la pagina
    if ((maxReg % pageSize) > 0) {
        pageCount += 1;
    }
    Label_PaginasClienes.setText("paginas" + "1" + "/" + String.valueOf(pageCount));
}
```

JBUTTON donde quiero mandar a llamar mi método:

```
private void ButtonRegistrar_Alumno1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                        
        new CambiaPanel(pnlPrincipal, new Paneles.PanelAlumnos());
}
```

Comment: Puedes agregar el código y pero no como imágenes.

Comment: @Bicho no puedo agregar imagenes?

Comment: No es recomendable, solo haz copy + paste del código directamente a tu pregunta y así es más legible para lectura; mira cómo preguntar en los links de ayuda del sitio.

Comment: @Bicho enseguida lo corrijo!

Comment: Qué tiene que ver la pregunta con JavaFX??

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Hola Many hace unos días tuve que solucionar un problema similar. 
Entiendo que lo que deseas lograr es: tener el table en un form2 aparte y tener un form1 que controle el ingreso de datos a tu table cierto?

Te dejare un link a un vídeo que me ayudo mucho, si ocupas ayuda veré como colaborar.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AdXu2sqLSjM&t=499s

Comment: Por favor lee [answer]

Comment: @AGiro gracias, lo veré :)

Comment: @AGiron como te indican otros usuarios, deberías añadir las partes claves del vídeo en la propia respuesta (manteniendo el enlace como referencia). Si el video es eliminado de youtube, esta respuesta dejará de tener sentido. Lee [answer] para más información.